# Oriented minimum bounding box tool missing from QGIS processing toolbox?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am working with QGIS 2.14.9 and I have realized that some processes are missing. For example, the Oriented Minimum Bounding Box (OMBB) tool is missing in QGIS vector general tools. It was the same with 2.14.7 version.

I have deleted the processing directory and re-launched QGIS without success.

Is there a way to "update" processing tools?

Comment: As idea, I was missing OrfeoToolBox once. It was not included in the 64bit installation. Installing 32bit solved it.

Comment: Same problem here (with 2.18.7) - I didn't even realise that OMBB was available in QGIS: I've been doing it externally in Python for three years with one of my typically kludgy scripts. I'm installing QGIS 2.18.9 and crossing fingers. If that doesn't do the trick, I will try and hunt down the cause and kill it with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I just did - which might be a superset of what is actually required, because it may be that the *'kill the **right** `processing` folder with fire'* is enough, and installing a different QGIS version is not necessary.

**1. Upgrade QGIS**

After I did that, I noticed that OMBB still was not present in `Processing->QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector General Tools`

**2. Upgrade `Processing` plugin**

First, open the Plugin Manager, and make a note of what version and folder it thinks it's supposed to be using for Processing. The image below is showing the **correct** version and folder pointer (for my Win7 box, at least).

Originally, the plugin Manager was showing Processing as a different version, in a directory in my folder on `c:\users\me\...\processing` - when I examined the folder I noticed its modification date was sometime in **2015**, despite the fact that I had literally just finished installing QGIS afresh 5 minutes beforehand. I am quite certain it's not 2015 (I've been wrong before: there was a time a few years ago when it was 2015 for the whole year).

I then got rid of the old directory.

Restarting QGIS afterwards gave a message that processing had trouble loading; a couple of config changes later (changing file pointers for GRASS), everything was smooth again and I was able to do OMBBs for an entire vector layer.
[image]

This was the result:

[image]