# QGIS 3.4 Layer Properties Update Extents to minimum bounding box of features

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

When I use QGIS 3.4.4 on Windows 10 and right click on a layer then select Zoom to Layer I zoom to half of the earth even though the 3 items on the layer are within 50 meters of each other.   I tried to use QGIS Layer Properties - Update Extents Button (See screen shot) and this really did not do much.  I then used the Python Console to set layer extents from a rectangle.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
rectang1 = QgsRectangle (-30878130,17423412,-30877366,17422953)
layer.setExtent(rectang1)
'''Michigan South'''
```

That worked fine.   I only do this once in awhile.   ***Is there another button in QGIS that will reset a layers extents to the minimum bounding box?***

The processing toolbox has an excellent tool to generate the Bounding geometry but I want to set the layer's extents not just find it.  [Oriented minimum bounding box tool missing from QGIS processing toolbox?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220424/oriented-minimum-bounding-box-tool-missing-from-qgis-processing-toolbox)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resaving the layer (`right-click > Export > Save Features As`). There is an option to set the extent of the output.

Comment: Yes.  Exporting and resetting the extent does work.  Thanks   I was just thinking that this is what the  Update Extents button was for.